# Why does loading a new html page reset javascript variables? How do I save those variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this piece of code in an html file called demo.html

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="src/San_Francisco_Opera_House.jpg" 
onclick="buyFunction('src/San_Francisco_Opera_House.jpg', 
'SF opera house', 'price: $360,000')" alt="Card image cap">
```

This runs this javascript function which loads a new HTML page. I want to display the image in the new page,

```
 function buyFunction(housePhotoString, addressString, priceString) {
     $(location).attr('href', 'buy.html');

     houseAttributes.housePhoto = housePhotoString;
     houseAttributes.address = addressString;
     houseAttributes.price = priceString;



     $(document).ready(function() {

         setPicturePriceAndAddress();

     });
 };

 function setPicturePriceAndAddress() {

     let strHTML = "";

     strHTML +=
         +"<img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"" + houseAttributes.housePhoto + "alt=\"Card image cap\">" +
         "<div class=\"card-block\">" +
         "<h4 class=\"card-title\">" +
         "</i>" + houseAttributes.address + "</h4>" +
         "<p class=\"card-text\">" + houseAttributes.price + "</p>" +
         "</div>";



     $("#housePhotoBuy").html(strHTML);


 };
```

But all the values gets reset. Or is there another way to send information to the new html file without having to save variables?

Comment: Javascript on one page is gone once you load a new page. You can store data in locaStorage or post it to server side script. Note that as soon as you start the redirect nothing else will exectute

Comment: Suggestion: Look into [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially store the variables in session storage on demo.html and then call them inside of buy.html

**demo.html:**

```
function buyFunction(housePhotoString, addressString, priceString) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('housePhoto', housePhotoString);
    sessionStorage.setItem('address', addressString);
    sessionStorage.setItem('price', priceString);
    $(location).attr('href', 'buy.html');
}
```

**buy.html:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var housePhotoString = sessionStorage.getItem('housePhoto');
    var addressString = sessionStorage.getItem('address');
    var priceString = sessionStorage.getItem('price');
    setPicturePriceAndAddress(housePhotoString, addressString, priceString);

 });

function setPicturePriceAndAddress(housePhotoString, addressString, priceString) {

    let strHTML = "";

    strHTML +=
     +"<img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"" + housePhotoString + "alt=\"Card image cap\">" +
     "<div class=\"card-block\">" +
     "<h4 class=\"card-title\">" +
     "</i>" + addressString + "</h4>" +
     "<p class=\"card-text\">" + priceString + "</p>" +
     "</div>";

     $("#housePhotoBuy").html(strHTML);
};
```

Comment: Note that sessionStorage is not persistent, if you want the data to hang around use localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client side language. Basically it is run on the web browser when it loads the page. Therefore, when a particular page is unloaded (moving away from the page, going to another page, closing the tab etc), the javascript values used in the page is flushed unless you take measures to save them.

For this, you can look into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) which saves the data in the browser and can be reused. Another method you can use is to set [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) which can also allow you to store and retrieve data from the user's browser between page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the variable in the localstorage and access the variables from anywhere under the same domain name , i.e you can use it another html file specified under same domain name

for example for your sample I created a little http server and then made a POC out of that

say your main script is contained in some index.html as your code block like this

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">


 function buyFunction(housePhotoString, addressString, priceString) {
     $(location).attr('href', 'buy.html');

     houseAttributes.housePhoto = housePhotoString;
     houseAttributes.address = addressString;
     houseAttributes.price = priceString;



     $(document).ready(function() {
         //pass the houseAttributes object to setPicturePriceandAddress for better use of functions in js   
         setPicturePriceAndAddress(houseAttributes);

     });
 };

 function setPicturePriceAndAddress(houseAttributes) {

     let strHTML = "";

     strHTML =
         "<img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"" + houseAttributes.housePhoto + "alt=\"Card image cap\">" +
         "<div class=\"card-block\">" +
         "<h4 class=\"card-title\">" +
         "</i>" + houseAttributes.address + "</h4>" +
         "<p class=\"card-text\">" + houseAttributes.price + "</p>" +
         "</div>";
    console.log('data',strHTML);
    //storing only for one time
    var dataToSave = localStorage.setItem('strHtml',strHTML)

    //storing for multiple time
    var arr = [];

    if(localStorage.getItem('arrOfStr')){
        arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arrOfStr'))
    }  
    arr.push(strHTML);
    localStorage.setItem('arrOfStr',JSON.stringify(arr))




     $("#housePhotoBuy").html(strHTML);


 };

 function getSavedValue(){
    var data = localStorage.getItem('strHtml')
    var data2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arrOfStr'))
    console.log(data,data2);
 }

 </script>
 </html>
```

Then you are accessing if in your file buy.html file

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Buy</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSavedValue(){
    var data = localStorage.getItem('strHtml')
    var data2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arrOfStr'))
    console.log(data,data2);
 }
 getSavedValue()

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and under the same domain name like for example if your index.html is in http://localhost:5000

and your buy.html is in http://localhost:5000/buy.html then you will be able to retrive all values stored in the buy.html in form of array if you want to store all the responses for a particular client or you can just access one single variable.I have made both the example you can use whatever you like according to your choice. If it's less than 5mb or something like that you can use localstorage and it is better to use than in cookie or session storage because they serve different purposes and they should be kept apart for saving extra data like this buy information for a particular client

Comment: Can't call `setPicturePriceAndAddress();` after the redirect is initialized. Changing the href will block other code

Comment: then redirect inside the setPicturePriceAddress() , you could invoke the setPicturePriceAddress() on click and then inside the function do the redirect.